# Why do minified version of CSS loads faster?

Tags: html, css

It is recommended to use a minified version of CSS for production environments, as minified versions of CSS loads faster; but what makes a minified version of CSS load faster?

Comment: because it has lesser code!! :)

Comment: Less characters in a file = less file size = faster download time.

Comment: ok how come it has the lesser codes?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Comment: `body { property: value; /*comment */ }` has more bytes than `body{property:value;}`, which would be the minified version.

Comment: Worth noting - because it's not immediately apparent to logical thinking - that spaces and other whitespace characters are still characters, and hence increase the file size.

Comment: Other than simply remove the white space / comment. \
I am more curious on the side of something like: is there things like JIT compiler that optimize the code \
--ie code's real business logic doesnt change, but the code order/underlying structure/logic flow changed, so to code run faster. \
Also benchmark of how much faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Minified" CSS (or javascript, or HTML or whatever) is a version of a file that has been reduced in size - normally by some automated process.

**The aim of minimising is to make it smaller, and thus quicker to download, without changing the behaviour of the code / markup / whatever.**

For CSS this is normally just a case of reducing the amount of whitespace and removing comments.  Basically taking out characters that will have no effect on the behaviour.

The downside of minimising is that it makes the file more difficult for humans to read.  many of the 'superfluous' characters are used to make the files more readable.

It is for this reason that minified versions are generally *only* used in production environments - or where the file is not intended to be changed by the developer (e.g. a jQuery library).

It is usually an automated process so that developers can work on a human readable version, and then the files are minimised *as* the deployment is made to production.

For other file types (Javascript, HTML, etc) the minimisation process may go further than just remove superfluous characters.  For example variable, function and class names will be shortened (e.g. `thingThatMeansSomethingToYou` may become `a`).

In all cases the aim is the same - **behaviour of the code remains the same, but the size of the file is reduced.**

Comment: I think the key point of this answer is not the bolded section.  The key reason why this is the correct answer is **thus quicker to download**

Comment: @GreenAsJade Good point, well made, answer updated.

Answer (score 5):

It loads usually faster because minified CSS/JS file is simply smaller in size, so it takes less to download and process.

See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Comment: what makes it smaller in size?

Comment: I actually think this is a decent question.  Does it take less time to parse?  Or just less time to download?

Comment: "what makes it smaller in size?" Did you compare a minified file to one that isn't before asking?

Comment: both. you got less data to load and then less data to work on (like less white spaces, newlines, no comments)

Comment: Yes- I agree with Rob Baille.  THis answer implies that the speedup is due to loading and parsing delay, wheras I was under the impression its the download time that's being sped up by having a smaller file.  Quoting from the link in this answer: "Minified source code is especially useful for interpreted languages deployed and transmitted on the Internet (such as JavaScript), because it reduces the amount of data that needs to be transferred."

Comment: I'd be interested to see a benchmark that shows that the parsing time of a minified file is noticeably lower..

Comment: I imagine that there probably is a marginal improvement in parse time, but I suspect that the amount of time saved ignoring whitespace and comments is generally insignificant in comparison to the saving on download time.  IMO Stripping such things is probably not expensive.  However - I have no numbers to back this up and so would be interested to hear a counter argument.

Answer (score 5):

It is stripped of all unnecessary parts (spaces, newlines, comments) resulting in a smaller file.